# UndeliverableException on a simple Observer. I don't understand where come from

Tags: java, android, rx-java, azure-maps

The error message is:

> The exception could not be delivered to the consumer because it has already canceled/disposed the flow or the exception has nowhere to go to begin with.

I cant get where it comes from...

From where I've been searching, the problem is on error handling, which I don't know where should I do it.
I need to solve this as fast as I can if you guys can help me out.

So my LocationService:

```
public class LocationService extends Service {
    public static ArrayList<LatLng> locationArrayList = new ArrayList<LatLng>();

    FusedLocationProviderClient fusedLocationClient;
    LocationRequest locationRequest;
    LocationCallback locationCallback;
    Context context;


    private void startLocationUpdates() {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.

            return;
        }

        fusedLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(locationRequest,
                locationCallback,
                Looper.getMainLooper());
    }

    protected void createLocationRequest() {
        LocationRequest locationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
        locationRequest.setInterval(3000);
        locationRequest.setFastestInterval(5000);
        locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    }



    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        RxJavaPlugins.setErrorHandler(emptyConsumer());
        new Notification();


        fusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);

        createNotificationChanel() ;

        locationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
        locationRequest.setInterval(7000);
        locationRequest.setFastestInterval(3000);
        locationRequest.setMaxWaitTime(5000);
        locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);



        locationCallback = new LocationCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onLocationResult(@NonNull LocationResult locationResult) {
                Location location =  locationResult.getLastLocation();
                assert location != null;
                com.aeroprotechnik.mismart.utils.NotificationManager.updateNotificationMessage(new LLcoor(location.getLongitude(), location.getLatitude()));




                //locationArrayList.add(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()));

               /* for (Location location : locationResult.getLocations()) {
                  location
                }*/
            }
        };
        startLocationUpdates();

        RxJavaPlugins.setErrorHandler(emptyConsumer());
    }




    private static void sendMessageToActivity(Context context ,double latitude, double longitude) {
        Intent intent = new Intent("GPSLocationUpdates");
        // You can also include some extra data.
        intent.putExtra("latitude", latitude);
        intent.putExtra("longitude", longitude);
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).sendBroadcast(intent);
    }

    private void createNotificationChanel() {
        String notificationChannelId = "Location channel id";
        String channelName = "Background Service";

        NotificationChannel chan = new NotificationChannel(
                notificationChannelId,
                channelName,
                NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_NONE
        );
        chan.setLightColor(Color.BLUE);
        chan.setLockscreenVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PRIVATE);

        NotificationManager manager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);

        manager.createNotificationChannel(chan);

        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, notificationChannelId);

        Notification notification = notificationBuilder.setOngoing(true)
                .setContentTitle("Location updates:")
                .setPriority(NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_MIN)
                .setCategory(Notification.CATEGORY_SERVICE)
                .build();
        startForeground(2, notification);
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        fusedLocationClient.removeLocationUpdates(locationCallback);
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }


}
```

My NotificationLiveData:

```
public class NotificationLiveData extends LiveData<LLcoor> {
    public void setNotification(LLcoor coor){
        postValue(coor);
    }
}
```

My manager:

```
public class NotificationManager extends LiveData<LLcoor> {

    private static final NotificationLiveData notificationLiveData = new NotificationLiveData();



    public static void updateNotificationMessage(LLcoor data){
        RxJavaPlugins.setErrorHandler(emptyConsumer());

        notificationLiveData.setNotification(data);

    }

    public static NotificationLiveData getNotificationLiveData() {
        return notificationLiveData;
    }
}
```

My observer:

```
  private final Observer<LLcoor> notificationObserver = new Observer<LLcoor>() {

        @Override
        public void onChanged(LLcoor coor) {
            Feature f = Feature.fromGeometry(Point.fromLngLat(coor.getLongitude(), coor.getLatitude()));
            Log.e("FEATURE ADDED", f.toString());
            mypos.clear();
            mypos.add(f);

        }
    };
```

Error Log:

```
io.reactivex.exceptions.UndeliverableException: The exception could not be delivered to the consumer because it has already canceled/disposed the flow or the exception has nowhere to go to begin with. Further reading: https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/What's-different-in-2.0#error-handling | android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Drawable com.aeroprotechnik.mismart:color/azure_maps_bg_dark with resource ID #0x7f06001d
        at io.reactivex.plugins.RxJavaPlugins.onError(RxJavaPlugins.java:367)
        at io.reactivex.internal.observers.ConsumerSingleObserver.onSuccess(ConsumerSingleObserver.java:65)
        at io.reactivex.internal.operators.single.SingleObserveOn$ObserveOnSingleObserver.run(SingleObserveOn.java:81)
        at io.reactivex.android.schedulers.HandlerScheduler$ScheduledRunnable.run(HandlerScheduler.java:124)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:907)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:216)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7625)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:524)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:987)
     Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Drawable com.aeroprotechnik.mismart:color/azure_maps_bg_dark with resource ID #0x7f06001d
     Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/color/azure_maps_bg_dark.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f06001d
        at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawableForCookie(ResourcesImpl.java:1166)
        at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawable(ResourcesImpl.java:917)
        at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawableForDensity(Resources.java:1074)
        at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:1013)
        at android.content.Context.getDrawable(Context.java:630)
        at android.view.View.setBackgroundResource(View.java:21728)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView.setBackgroundResource(AppCompatTextView.java:144)
        at com.azure.android.maps.control.CopyrightDelegate.b(SourceFile:3)
        at com.azure.android.maps.control.CopyrightDelegate.$r8$lambda$35Myr-cFRF2s-DrL_gjzL00mHSc(Unknown Source:0)
        at com.azure.android.maps.control.CopyrightDelegate$$ExternalSyntheticLambda3.accept(Unknown Source:4)
        at io.reactivex.internal.observers.ConsumerSingleObserver.onSuccess(ConsumerSingleObserver.java:62)
        at io.reactivex.internal.operators.single.SingleObserveOn$ObserveOnSingleObserver.run(SingleObserveOn.java:81)
        at io.reactivex.android.schedulers.HandlerScheduler$ScheduledRunnable.run(HandlerScheduler.java:124)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:907)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:216)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7625)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:524)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:987)
     Caused by: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line #3: <item> tag requires a 'drawable' attribute or child tag defining a drawable
        at android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable.inflateChildElements(StateListDrawable.java:190)
        at android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable.inflate(StateListDrawable.java:122)
        at android.graphics.drawable.DrawableInflater.inflateFromXmlForDensity(DrawableInflater.java:148)
        at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInnerForDensity(Drawable.java:1332)
        at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlForDensity(Drawable.java:1291)
        at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawableForCookie(ResourcesImpl.java:1144)
        at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawable(ResourcesImpl.java:917) 
        at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawableForDensity(Resources.java:1074) 
        at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:1013) 
        at android.content.Context.getDrawable(Context.java:630) 
        at android.view.View.setBackgroundResource(View.java:21728) 
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView.setBackgroundResource(AppCompatTextView.java:144) 
        at com.azure.android.maps.control.CopyrightDelegate.b(SourceFile:3) 
        at com.azure.android.maps.control.CopyrightDelegate.$r8$lambda$35Myr-cFRF2s-DrL_gjzL00mHSc(Unknown Source:0) 
        at com.azure.android.maps.control.CopyrightDelegate$$ExternalSyntheticLambda3.accept(Unknown Source:4) 
        at io.reactivex.internal.observers.ConsumerSingleObserver.onSuccess(ConsumerSingleObserver.java:62) 
        at io.reactivex.internal.operators.single.SingleObserveOn$ObserveOnSingleObserver.run(SingleObserveOn.java:81) 
        at io.reactivex.android.schedulers.HandlerScheduler$ScheduledRunnable.run(HandlerScheduler.java:124) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:907) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:216) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7625) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:524) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:987) 
2023-02-01 12:30:36.490 14329-14359/com.aeroprotechnik.mismart E/AwareLog: AtomicFileUtils: readFileLines file not exist: android.util.AtomicFile@d86ec08
2023-02-01 12:30:36.492 14329-14359/com.aeroprotechnik.mismart E/AwareLog: AtomicFileUtils: readFileLines file not exist: android.util.AtomicFile@48d1fa1
2023-02-01 12:30:36.518 14329-14350/com.aeroprotechnik.mismart E/MemoryLeakMonitorManager: MemoryLeakMonitor.jar is not exist!
2023-02-01 12:30:39.070 14329-14340/com.aeroprotechnik.mismart E/: [ZeroHung]zrhung_get_config: Get config failed for wp[0x0008]
```

Comment: That `Observer` doesn't look like an RxJava one. Where is even RxJava involved other than suppressing the undeliverable exception? Most inportantly though, why haven't you posted the **full stacktrace**?

Comment: @akarnokd im kinda newbie in android, by stacktrace you mean full error log ?

Comment: @akarnokd And yes, i tought i wasn't using RxJava, but the error log talks about rxJava and that error handling in the code was a try to fix the exception. Because the app works fine in android 10, this just happpens when im in android 9. Forgot to mencion that.

Comment: Yes, please post the error log where it stats saying `The exception could not be delivered` followed by a bunch of `at some.packages` and also `caused by`. But don't post it in the comments! Edit the question please.

Comment: @akarnokd https://prnt.sc/9hNzKgfao4gA

Comment: Please do not post screenshots of errors. Edit your question with the text.

Comment: @akarnokd i've edited, sorry

Comment: Please copy-paste the error text and add that to the question **as text**!

Comment: As in stacktrace there is an issue with loading resource: res/color/azure_maps_bg_dark.xml Can you check an post content of the file ? Maybe you reference color that doesn't exist or maybe resource it's referencing itself

Comment: @bongo if thats the problem, how could i/you explain the app working on android version 10 and above, and not working in android 9 ?

Comment: @akarnokd sry, i did that just now. Thanks

Comment: @bongo and i think that resource comes from the library im using, azure maps.

Comment: Not sure what the difficulty is; just reading the error message I see this:

*org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line #3: <item> tag requires a 'drawable' attribute or child tag defining a drawable*. Probably `drawable` is optional in 10 but mandatory in 9? Maybe the resource/library is no longer compatible with 9?

Comment: @akarnokd hmm, if we talking about azure maps lib it is compatible, because in my version 1.01 it was working fine. So you are telling me that is nothing about my Observer but about a xml file ?

Comment: To be honest, this library is really outdated it is still using support v4 library and not appcompat

Comment: @bongo so i should change the library ? Can you advice me one good map LIB that can handle 100 000 points like this one ?

Comment: which version of the library are you using? Can you check If there is error when u user 1.2.0 version ?

Comment: I have checked the source code of version 1.2.0 and I can't find problematic resources "azure_maps_bg_dark" so maybe it was fixed already

Comment: @bongo when i talk about version, i was talking about my app, the version of azure maps im using is: 
//AZURE MAPS
    implementation 'com.azure.android:azure-maps-control:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.9.0-alpha01'

Comment: Ok so let's try this
create azure_maps_btn_bg_dark.xml file in drawable folder and paste this as a content:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent">
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="@color/azure_maps_bg_dark" />
            <corners android:radius="2dp" />
            <stroke android:color="#00000080" android:width="1px" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>

Comment: i've tried this minutes ago with this code :
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:color="#43474c"/>
    <item android:color="#011C2C"/>
</selector>

Comment: Anyway tried with yours, and didnt work anyway. Im start to give up, im just going to say the minimum android it has to be 10

Comment: But can at least check if the exception was the same? Probably there are more resources that needs tweaks

Comment: @bongo the resource didnt exist. It comes from the library. I just tryed to create one myself